# AWK function w/ a variable number of arguments

Tags: awk, variadic-functions

How to define an AWK function w/ a variable number of arguments? I can emulate this w/ command line arguments:

```
awk 'BEGIN {for (i in ARGV) printf ARGV[i]" "}' 1 2 3
```

but `BEGIN {for (i in ARGV) printf ARGV[i]" "}` isn't a function (in AWK).

Currently I'm using MAWK (but can probably switch to GAWK if it would help)

NOTE: I cannot reveal the task (it's an exercise which I'm supposed to solve by myself)

Comment: Your question is not clear, you need to do the same operation(printing all file names or arguments passed to `awk`) in a function? could you please clarify more on same once.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 No I don't. This is just an example showing all the command line arguments

Comment: Could you please do add more details in your question, its not clear as of now(what expected output/outcome you are looking for), thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I know how to get the output once I have the input. However, I'd like to have the input to a function, so the problem is in defining a variadic AWK function

Comment: Sure, if you could show samples of input and expected output in your question that will give us better picture and yes we can do it with function.

Comment: Variadic = w/ a variable number of arguments. If AWK's function declaration syntax is only `function name(x, y, ...)`, where `x, y, ...` is optional, then I can't see how to get a variable number of arguments. But maybe it isn't (I'm not an expert)

Comment: Could you please check `awk -v var="var1,var2,var3,var4,var5" 'BEGIN{num=split(var,arr,",");for(i=1;i<=num;i++){print i,arr[i]}}'` if this is what you are looking here? Pass all values which you want to access in `awk` program in an `awk` variable named `var` and split it inside `BEGIN` section and you can get all items values with use of array. Let me know if this is what you are looking for?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Not what I wanted (as `BEGIN..` is not a function) but better than my attempt (and I'm learning something new, so thanks)

Comment: It was more like a guess, If you could give me an example of explain me more may be I could try to help more, thank you.

Comment: There are no variadic functions because they're not needed and the key to the conciseness and power of the awk language is that it only provides constructs for functionality that isn't easy to implement yourself using existing constructs. If you [edit] your question to show a [mcve] that demonstrates what you're trying to do (as opposed to just how you're trying to do it) then we can help you do whatever that is the right way in awk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no variadic functions in awk because they're not needed since you can just populate an array and pass that into a function:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    split("foo 17 bar",a)
    foo(a)
}

function foo(arr,       i,n) {
    n = length(arr)     # or loop incrementing n if length(arr) unsupported
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", arr[i], (i<n ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
$ awk -f tst.awk
foo 17 bar
```

or just define the function with a bunch of dummy argument names as @triplee mentions.

Comment: I really like that simpe but very elegant `(i<n ? OFS : ORS)` "trick" : is there a good place (url or book) with a compendium of good "[gnm]?awk" usefull bits?

Comment: @OlivierDulac not that I know of, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

As per https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Variadic_function you can define a function with more arguments than you pass in; the ones you omit will come out as empty.

It's not clear from your example what you are actually trying to accomplish, but this is the answer to your actual question.

```
$ awk 'function handlemany(first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth, seventh, eighth, ninth, tenth, eleventh, twelfth) {
>   print first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixt, seventh, eighth, ninth, tenth, eleventh, twelfth
> }
> BEGIN { handlemany("one", "two", "three") }'
one two three
```

This is less than ideal, of course, but there is no support for proper variadic functions / `varargs` in the Awk language.