# gawk: Local variables typed differently in SYMTAB

Tags: awk

Function parameters seem to be typed differently in the SYMTAB array than if you check them directly.
i.e. `typeof(p)` is not always equal to `typeof(SYMTAB["p"])`

I'm trying to write a generic function to initialize a one-dimensional array, with a variable number of elements. This issue is specific to gawk as it uses the SYMTAB array that doesn't exist in standard awk.

For example:

```
array_new(array1, 1, 2, "c", 4, "e")
array_new(array2, 99, 98, 97)

function array_new(arr, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6) {
   # initialization code
}
```

gawk doesn't allow for optional parameters, so I have set a reasonable upper limit - 6 for the example above but in practice I've been using 20 - and then within the function I only want to create elements for which a value has been given.
A first "brute force" approach that I've tried, and which works, is as follows :

```
function array_new(arr, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6) {
    delete arr
    if (typeof(p1)  != "untyped") arr[1] = p1
    if (typeof(p2)  != "untyped") arr[2] = p2
    if (typeof(p3)  != "untyped") arr[3] = p3
    if (typeof(p4)  != "untyped") arr[4] = p4
    if (typeof(p5)  != "untyped") arr[5] = p5
    if (typeof(p6)  != "untyped") arr[6] = p6
    return
}
```

But the more parameters I want to allow, the more unwieldy this becomes, so I wanted to loop through the parameters and exit as soon as an uninitialized one is encountered.

So I tried the following, but it doesn't work :

```
function array_new_2(arr, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, n) {
    for (n=1; n<=6; n++) {
        if (typeof(SYMTAB["p"n]) != "untyped") arr[n] = SYMTAB["p"n]
        else break
    }
    return
}
```

Trying to understand why I ran some tests, and it turns out that typeof(p...) is "string", "number" or "untyped" depending on what is passed to the function, or not, but typeof(SYMTAB["p"n]) is always "unassigned".

This is my complete code, with some debugging "print" statements added to see what is happening:

```
END {
    array_new_1(aaa, 3, 2, 1)
    array_walk(aaa, "aaa")
    print ""

    array_new_2(bbb, "a", "b", "c")
    array_walk(bbb, "bbb")
    print ""
}

function array_walk(arr, name,     i) {
    for (i in arr) {
        if (isarray(arr[i]))
            array_walk(arr[i], (name "[" i "]"))
        else
            printf("%s[%s] = '%s'\n", name, i, arr[i]) 
    }
}

function array_new_1(arr, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6) {
    print "p1           : " typeof(p1), p1
    print "p6           : " typeof(p6), p6
    print "SYMTAB[\"p1\"] : " typeof(SYMTAB["p1"]), SYMTAB["p1"]
    print "SYMTAB[\"p6\"] : " typeof(SYMTAB["p6"]), SYMTAB["p6"]   # this creates an "unassigned" value
    if (typeof(p1)  != "untyped") arr[1] = p1
    if (typeof(p2)  != "untyped") arr[2] = p2
    if (typeof(p3)  != "untyped") arr[3] = p3
    if (typeof(p4)  != "untyped") arr[4] = p4
    if (typeof(p5)  != "untyped") arr[5] = p5
    if (typeof(p6)  != "untyped") arr[6] = p6
    return
}

function array_new_2(arr, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, n) {
    print "p1           : " typeof(p1), p1
    print "p6           : " typeof(p6), p6
    print "SYMTAB[\"p1\"] : " typeof(SYMTAB["p1"]), SYMTAB["p1"]
    print "SYMTAB[\"p6\"] : " typeof(SYMTAB["p6"]), SYMTAB["p1"]
    for (n=1; n<=6; n++) {
        if (typeof(SYMTAB["p"n]) == "unassigned") arr[n] = SYMTAB["p"n]
        else break
    }
    return
}
```

This produces the following output :

```
p1           : number 3
p6           : untyped 
SYMTAB["p1"] : unassigned 
SYMTAB["p6"] : unassigned 
aaa[1] = '3'
aaa[2] = '2'
aaa[3] = '1'
aaa[6] = ''

p1           : string a
p6           : untyped 
SYMTAB["p1"] : unassigned 
SYMTAB["p6"] : unassigned 
bbb[1] = ''
bbb[2] = ''
bbb[3] = ''
bbb[4] = ''
bbb[5] = ''
bbb[6] = ''
```

So, to sum up, can anyone explain why the SYMTAB versions of the parameters are typed differently from the variables themselves, and also, is there a better way to write my array_new function ?

Comment: Please reduce your code to a minimal (but still complete) example that's just enough to demonstrate the issue you're asking for help with to make it easier for us to help you. You should be able to write a function that's maybe 2 lines long and call it from BEGIN for a total script length of maybe 5 lines to be able to demonstrate `Function parameters seem to be typed differently in the SYMTAB array than if you check them directly.`

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I believe that explaining the issue and providing the code that I have makes things clearer and shows too that I have done some research.

Comment: Is this question asking how to pass variable numbers of args to a function or why Function parameters seem to be typed differently in the SYMTAB array than if you check them directly? I thought it was the latter but maybe not. If it's the former then this is a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/65032256/1745001.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Ed. My main question was about SYMTAB, which is probably why I hadn't found (or even looked for) the other question you link to. markp-fuso has answered below on both points. I've been using awk/gawk for over 20 years for work, but I'm only now moving from simple one-liners or short scripts to using gawk to prototype a personal project with currently over 3000 lines, which has forced me to dig much deeper into gawk possibilities, and shortcomings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking solely at the `SYMTAB[]` issue ...

It doesn't appear that `SYMTAB[]` is aware of 'local' parameters as defined in the function's parameter list unless they are also referenced in the body of the function, but even then it appears that `SYMTAB[<param>]` doesn't contain the value of the parameter.

Consider the following:

```
awk '
function array_new_2(arr, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, n) {

    print "p1",p1,SYMTAB["p1"],typeof(SYMTAB["p1"])
    print "p6",p6,SYMTAB["p6"],typeof(SYMTAB["p1"])
    print "XX",XX,SYMTAB["XX"],typeof(SYMTAB["XX"])

    print "############# pX in SYMTAB ?"

    for (i=1;i<=6;i++)
        print "p"i ("p"i in SYMTAB ? "" : " not") " in SYMTAB[]; SYMTAB[p"i"]=" SYMTAB["p"i]

    print "############# for loop:"

    for (i in SYMTAB)
        if (isarray(SYMTAB[i]) )
           print i,"[ array ]"
        else
           print i,SYMTAB[i]

    print "#############"

    arr[1]=p1
}

BEGIN {
    OFS=","
    array_new_2(arrX,1,2,3)    # provide values for p1/p2/p3
}
'
```

This generates:

```
p1,1,,unassigned                   # SYMTAB["p1"] is empty/undefined
p6,,,unassigned                    # no value supplied for p6, SYMTAB["p6"] is empty/undefined
XX,,,unassigned                    # undefined variable "XX"

############# pX in SYMTAB ?
p1 in SYMTAB[]; SYMTAB[p1]=        # in SYMTAB[] because referenced in body of function, but value not in SYMTAB[] !!
p2 not in SYMTAB[]; SYMTAB[p2]=    # value provided but not in SYMTAB[] !!
p3 not in SYMTAB[]; SYMTAB[p3]=    # value provided but not in SYMTAB[] !!
p4 not in SYMTAB[]; SYMTAB[p4]=
p5 not in SYMTAB[]; SYMTAB[p5]=
p6 in SYMTAB[]; SYMTAB[p6]=        # no value provided but in SYMTAB[] because referenced in body of function

############# for loop:
ARGV,[ array ]
i,i
ROUNDMODE,N
ORS,

OFS,,
LINT,0
FNR,0
ERRNO,
NR,0
IGNORECASE,0
p1,                                # referenced in body of function; SYMTAB[] is empty/undefined
TEXTDOMAIN,messages
NF,0
ARGIND,0
arrX,[ array ]                     # without "arr[1]=p1" the variable "arrX" is treated as a scalar and SYMTAB["arrX"] is empty/undefined
XX,
ARGC,1
PROCINFO,[ array ]
FIELDWIDTHS,
CONVFMT,%.6g
SUBSEP,
PREC,53
ENVIRON,[ array ]
RS,

FPAT,[^[:space:]]+
p6,                                # referenced in body of function; SYMTAB[] is empty/undefined
RT,
RLENGTH,0
OFMT,%.6g
FS, 
RSTART,0
FILENAME,
BINMODE,0
#############
```

**NOTES:**

- `p1` (=1) and `p6` (empty/undefined) show up in `for` loop output because they are referenced in the body of function
- `p2` (=2) and `p3` (=3) have values supplied by the function call but they are never referenced in the body of the function soooo, they don't show up in the `for` loop output
- `p4`(empty/undefined) and `p5` (empty/undefined) are never referenced in the body of the function soooo, they also don't show up in the `for` loop output

From this small test it appears:

- `SYMTAB[]` cannot be used to determine if a function's input parameters were supplied values
- `SYMTAB[]` cannot be used to access the actual values passed in the function call

Comment: As the manual says, "An array whose indices are the names of all defined global variables and arrays in the program" and function args are neither of those things. I'm surprised you're not getting a semantic error trying to lookup SYMTAB using `p1`. Which version of gawk are you running? That may be a bug.

Comment: Thanks @markp-fuso, I hadn't thought of using split in that way here, although I do already use it regularly for exactly that. And thanks too for the additional tests on SYMTAB, and for Ed's comment, which points out the manual to _global_ vars. It was the SYMTAB issue that was troubling me the most, as the function was a helper to keep my library of array functions consistent, and I wanted to understand why SYMTAB's behaviour seems inconsistent. I'm using gawk 5.1.

Comment: FWIW when I run that script in gawk 5.2.1 I get ```awk: cmd. line:4: fatal: reference to uninitialized element `SYMTAB["p1"] is not allowed'``` so if you can in 5.1 then that sounds like a bug. One reason that can't be allowed is that if there were also a global variable named `p1` and you were allowed to look up SYMTAB by function-local as well as global variables, then there wouldn't be a way to look up the global `p1` in SYMTAB inside a function since the global value would be masked by the local one and there's no way to identify which `p1` you want to look up.

Comment: That's a good point about scope and which variable would be referenced by SYMTAB["p1"]. Thanks both for your assistance. As an aside, can you point me to a site where I can download the latest windows version of gawk. I've been trying to find one and all I can find is either out-of-date versions, or the GNU non-compiled source distributions.

Comment: @EdMorton fwiw, I get similar error messages when running OP's code under `cygwin/gawk 5.2.1` but no errors are generated (and in fact I get the same output as OP's code) when running under `ubuntu/gawk 5.1.0`; at this point I'm writing this off to something 'off' with the `cygwin/gawk` compilation

Comment: I really think it's just a plain old bug in gawk 5.1.0 (or maybe better to characterize it as an enhancement in gawk 5.2?) as trying to access a non-existent entry in `SYMTAB[]` should report an error.

Comment: @cjnwl not sure what you mean by `windows version of gawk` ... `cygwin` appears to have an up-to-date version of `gawk` (5.2.1-2 at last check); if running linux under windows (WSL?) I'd expect the associated distribution (eg, ubuntu) to have an up-to-date version; if you're running some other software (mks?), *shrug* ....

Comment: I'm looking for a windows executable install file (gawk.exe + bundled libs, folders, etc), not linux or cygwin. I can't remember where I downloaded 5.1 from and I can't find a download site for anything more recent than 4.1.6...

Comment: Cygwin does seem to be what I'm looking for actually, but I still can't find where to download anything other than .zst file, whereas I know that in the past for previous releases (v4.x, v5.0, 5.1) I've been able to find a windows installation file

Comment: re: cygwin ... can't speak to the *zst comment; cygwin is more of a package installer; [main site](https://cygwin.org/); you [download the exe](https://cygwin.org/setup-x86_64.exe); run the *exe, follow instructions, pick from the various packages you wish to install (eg, shells, binaries, etc); periodically re-run the *exe to check for new/updated packages and/or to install a package you've now decided you want to use

Comment: I meant to say that the *exe is a package installer ... run it each time you want to install/update a package within the cygwin env

Comment: @ to all : that's not a bug at all. There are 4 entries in the `gawk` change log detailing arnold's recent changes to `SYMTAB` :  (those are line #s)
:::::::::
   `305 Disallow SYMTAB["x"]["y"].`:::::::::
  `485 PROCINFO["identifiers"] is like SYMTAB and FUNCTAB. This makes` :::::::::
   `579 FUNCTAB and SYMTAB to create new elements.  Thanks to` ::::::::::
  `1030 Disallow SYMTAB and FUNCTAB as destination arguments to builtin`

Answer (score 2):

In appears (to me) that the `SYMTAB[]/typing` question is a diversion from the main issue of figuring out how to (efficiently) provide a variable number of input parameters to an `awk` function. [**NOTE:** This is similar to the issue of wanting to feed a variable number of values on the command line via several `-v var=val` clauses.]

One common workaround is to concatenate the (variable) list of values into a single delimited string, then have the code `split()` this delimited string into a variable length array of values.

Applying this to OP's case:

```
array_new(array1, "1,2,c,4,e")             # concatenate the list of values into a comma-delimited string

function array_new{arr, plist) { 
   n=split(plist,p,",") ...                # split the comma-delimited string into an array named p[], with "n" elements in the array
   for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {                    # loop through the indices of the p[] array (1 to n)
       # do something with p[i]
   }
}
```

If the sole purpose of OP's function is to populate an array then we can use the input parameter (`arr`) as the target of the `split()` call, eg:

```
function array_new(arr, plist) {
    split(plist,arr,",")
}
```

Running some tests:

```
array_new(array1, "1,2,c,4,e")
print "########### array1"
for (i=1;i<=length(array1);i++)
    print "array1[" i "] = " array1[i]

array_new(array2, "99,98,97")
print "########### array2"
for (i=1;i<=length(array2);i++)
    print "array2[" i "] = " array2[i]
```

This generates:

```
########### array1
array1[1] = 1
array1[2] = 2
array1[3] = c
array1[4] = 4
array1[5] = e
########### array2
array2[1] = 99
array2[2] = 98
array2[3] = 97
```

**NOTE:** for this sample code I've used a comma as the delimiter; if the data could include commas then OP will (obviously) need to switch to a different delimiter (that doesn't show up in the data)

---

Then again, if OP's only need for the function is to populate the array, there's really no need for a user-defined function to serve as a wrapper for the `awk` supplied `split()` function.

In other words, all of this:

```
array_new(array1, "1,2,c,4,e")
array_new(array2, "99,98,97")


function array_new(arr, plist) {
    split(plist,arr,",")
}
```

Can be replaced by this:

```
split("1,2,c,4,e", array1, ",")
split("99,98,97",  array2, ",")
```